# angular how to dynamically add a list of components

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-components

So basically i have a button that give me the choice to add a component that contains 2 inputs . and they user can add this component multiple times . but i tried  `ComponentFactoryResolver` but it can only add one component at the time . 
[image]

when i press add contract i will a component who is a card that contains an input fields and label

Comment: Please provide a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: You could use ngFor and push new items to the iterable

Comment: its an component you can push components with ngfor i guess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Use `*ngFor` to loop through a model which then shows the child

Given from the feature you want to achive, you need as in the comments already mentioned, model in the TS file which will be looped through in the HTML template with an `*ngFor`. Using this in combination with child components you can add those easily with for example a button click

TS Parent

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';
  // specifies the input data
  inputs = []

  addInput() {
    // Here you can specify the data
    this.inputs.push({});
  }
}
```

HTML Parent

```
<button (click)="addInput()">Add Input</button>
<app-child *ngFor="let input of inputs"></app-child>
```

HTML Child

```
<p> Input: </p>
<input type="text">
```

- To specify your child component you can use `@Input()` decorator. There you can pass the data in `input` to the child if you want for example show different forms or different elements.

For your refernce: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hrdtcu

Comment: i tried using this approach but lets say how i can track each component and what he do . and in my case i added 5 text fields and i need to validate them together how i can do it

Comment: Then you maybe should create a reactive form with a form array which you can iterate. This form then has a cross field validation which validates them all together

Comment: @Mohamed hassan kadri That's outside of scope.

Comment: but you can use reactive forms for that